# How to fix bootstrap path not working when I put it inside a folder

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-4, hyperlink

It is my first time using bootstrap 3, what I want to do is to make a header so that I will just call the file whenever I will create a new page but the problem is that when I created a folder and inside is index.php when I put the code from the original file it didn't work.

Here is the image of what I did

[image]

Here is the image of the original

[image]

Here is the code in html (only the link and script)

```
<link href="vendor/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link
    href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:200,200i,300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,700i,800,800i,900,900i"
    rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Custom styles for this template-->
<link href="css/sb-admin-2.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<!-- Core plugin JavaScript-->
<script src="vendor/jquery-easing/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>

<!-- Custom scripts for all pages-->
<script src="js/sb-admin-2.min.js"></script>

<!-- Page level plugins -->
<script src="vendor/chart.js/Chart.min.js"></script>

<!-- Page level custom scripts -->
<script src="js/demo/chart-area-demo.js"></script>
<script src="js/demo/chart-pie-demo.js"></script>
```

I don't clearly get it, I mean I accessed the file path and try to recode it but still it won't show the design and functions in jquery, I hope someone can explain me since I am new to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `/` to all `src` or `href`. it's different between `/vendor` and `vendor`.

you need to access file at root but not `page/vendor`